# Update the input value from one component in an other on runtime

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a NotificationStepper Component which gets inputs from user, I need to update this input value in run time in another component named TabComponent. Both of the components are child components of SendNotification Component. How can i achieve that in reactjs.

**EDIT**

NotificationStepper.js

```
const styles = {
    transparentBar: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        paddingTop: '25px',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
};


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        formControl: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 120,
        },
        selectEmpty: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
    }),
);

function getSteps() {
    return ['Create', 'Audience', 'Timing'];
}

function getStepContent(step, $this) {


    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return (
                <div className="row">
                    <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12"
                             heading="">
                        <form className="row" noValidate autoComplete="off" style={{"flex-wrap":"no-wrap", "flex-direction": "column" }}>
                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12">
                                <TextField
                                    id="campaign_name"
                                    label="Campaign Name"
                                    value={$this.state.name}
                                    onChange={$this.handleChange('name')}
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </CardBox>
                    
                </div>
                );
        default:
            return 'Unknown step';
    }
}

class NotificationStepper extends React.Component {
    state = {
        activeStep: 0,
        name: '',
    };

    handleChange = name => event => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };


    handleNext = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: this.state.activeStep + 1,
        });
    };

    handleBack = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: this.state.activeStep - 1,
        });
    };

    handleReset = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: 0,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const steps = getSteps();
        const {activeStep} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-7 col-12">
                <Stepper className="MuiPaper-root-custom" activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
                    {steps.map((label, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Step key={label}>
                                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                                <StepContent className="pb-3">
                                    <Typography>{getStepContent(index, this)}</Typography>
                                    <div className="mt-2">
                                        <div>
                                            <Button
                                                disabled={activeStep === 0}
                                                onClick={this.handleBack}
                                                className="jr-btn"
                                            >
                                                Back
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="contained"
                                                color="primary"
                                                onClick={this.handleNext}
                                                className="jr-btn"
                                            >
                                                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </StepContent>
                            </Step>
                        );
                    })}

                </Stepper>
                {activeStep === steps.length && (
                    <Paper square elevation={0} className="p-2">
                        <Typography>All steps completed - you&quot;re finished</Typography>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleReset} className="jr-btn">
                            Reset
                        </Button>
                    </Paper>
                )}


            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default NotificationStepper;
```

TabComponent.js

```
TabContainer.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    dir: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

class TabComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        value: 0,
    };


    render() {
        const {theme} = this.props;


        return (
            <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12" style={{"margin-top": "15px"}}>
                    <NotifCard  key={0} data={{'name': 'Title of Notification', 'company': 'sayge.ai', 'image': require("assets/images/chrome.png"), 'description': 'Notification Message here'}} styleName="card shadow "/>
                    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TabComponent.propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(null, {withTheme: true})(TabComponent);
```

and this is my SendNotification.js

```
const SendNotification = ({match}) => {
    return (

        <div className="dashboard animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3">

            <ContainerHeader match={match} title={<IntlMessages id="sidebar.notification"/>}/>
            <div className="row" style={{'flex-wrap': 'no wrap', "flex-direction": 'row'}}>
                <div className="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-7">
                    <NotificationStepper/>
                    <div className='flex-class' style={{'width': '100%'}}>
                        <Button color="primary" style={{"align-self": "flex-end", "border" : "1px solid", "margin-left": "10px", "margin-bottom": "40px"}} size="small" className="col-md-2 col-2">Fetch</Button>
                        <Button color="primary" style={{"align-self": "flex-end", "border" : "1px solid", "margin-left": "10px", "margin-bottom": "40px"}} size="small" className="col-md-2 col-2" color="primary">Discard</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-5" style={{"padding-top": "20px"}}>
                    <span style={{"margin-left" : "20px", "font-weight": "bold"}}>Preview</span>
                    <TabComponent />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default SendNotification;
```

i need to get the name value from NotificationStepper and Update it in pass it to  in TabComponent.

Comment: create a demo in codesandbox or provide code here so we can understand your situation more

Comment: Pass your value in the parent component, do your work on it then send it to the other component. It's just prop drilling. If you have only one level in your component tree then it's ok to use that. Else, you could go for a context

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine check edit

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials about that. For instance, [this](https://medium.com/trabe/react-useref-hook-b6c9d39e2022).

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

class CustomTextInput extends Component {
  textInput = createRef();

  focusTextInput = () => this.textInput.current.focus();

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
        <button onClick={this.focusTextInput}>Focus the text input</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const CustomTextInput = () => {
  const textInput = useRef();

  focusTextInput = () => textInput.current.focus();

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={textInput} />
      <button onClick={focusTextInput}>Focus the text input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```